# Can somebody do this trigonometry compound angle question?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos(A) + \sin(B) = x$ and $\sin(B) + \cos(A) = y$, prove that

$$\sin(A + B) = \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 2}{2}$$

Comment: Check your question... The expression for either $x$ or $y$ is most probably not correct...

Comment: Do you mean $y = \sin(A) + \cos(B)$?

Comment: Right... Alternatively the expression for $x$ should be different.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming**

$$x = \cos A + \sin B, y = \sin A + \cos B$$

We have

$$x^2 = \cos^2 A + \sin^2 B + 2 \cos A \sin B$$

$$y^2 = \sin^2 A + \cos^2 B + 2 \sin A \cos B$$

Adding, $$x^2 + y^2 = 2 + 2 \sin (A+B)$$

Or, $$\sin(A+B) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2 - 2)$$